# Laravel can't select from fusion table

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my code in laravel

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/testproject/test');
    $code=$request->get('code');
    $client->authenticate($code);
    $getfusion = new \Google_Service_Fusiontables($client); 
    $postbody=new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column();
    $service= new \Google_Service($client);
    $serviceName='query';
    $resourceName='select';
    $resource=$service->resource;
    $fusionTableQuery=new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_Query_Resource($service, $serviceName, $resourceName, $resource);
    $sql='SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $results=$fusionTableQuery->sql($sql, $optParams=array());
    dd($results);
```

shows an error like this :

```
Google_Exception in Resource.php line 87:
Unknown function:query->select->sql()
```

Any help will be appreciated!!